# Android: Best way to backup data to the internet?

Tags: java, android, database, jdbc

what would be the best way to backup data to a external location ie web server? ive looked in to sql and emailing and file upload but none of these seem to work using the android sdk? (i may be wrong) im trying to back up sms messages preferably to a database somewhere on the internet can anyone maybe suggest a way of doing this? as far as i can see JDBC isn't accessible on android?

thanks in advance.

heres the error i get when adding the JDBC:

```
        UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dx.util.ExceptionWithContext
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.util.ExceptionWithContext.withContext(ExceptionWithContext.java:46)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:340)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:131)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:85)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:369)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:346)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:59)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:294)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:130)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:190)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:122)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:108)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:313)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:233)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:185)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:179)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:585)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:490)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:239)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:292)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:295)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:256)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:394)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:618)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:114)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:145)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:854)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:703)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:928)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1132)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper$SubroutineInliner.involvedInSubroutine(Ropper.java:1518)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper$SubroutineInliner.mapOrAllocateLabel(Ropper.java:1539)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper$SubroutineInliner.copyBlock(Ropper.java:1457)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper$SubroutineInliner.inlineSubroutineCalledFrom(Ropper.java:1412)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.inlineSubroutines(Ropper.java:1286)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.doit(Ropper.java:652)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.convert(Ropper.java:252)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:252)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  ... 39 more
...while processing reuseAndReadPacket (Lcom/mysql/jdbc/Buffer;I)Lcom/mysql/jdbc/Buffer;
...while processing com/mysql/jdbc/MysqlIO.class

[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx 
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/mysql/jdbc/AssertionFailedException;
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:143)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:372)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:346)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:59)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:294)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:130)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:108)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:313)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:233)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:185)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:179)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:585)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:490)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:239)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:292)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:295)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:256)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:394)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:618)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:114)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:145)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:854)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:703)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:928)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1132)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Dx 2 errors; aborting
[2011-07-12 17:17:46 - SMS] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [SMS-backup-plus](https://github.com/jberkel/sms-backup-plus), it may be what you want.

Comment: i have all my methods in place except for the upload method i didn't really want to use the k9 email as the emailing facility. i just wanted to know how to connect to a sql database and add items to the table or to be able to upload the file to a server.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [Backup Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/backup/BackupManager.html) for Android. This won't necessarily work on demand, but will let the user keep his/her data in case it's needed.

If you have an SQL database, you can simply send the file by whatever method you need (uploading to your own server, for example).

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why you wouldn't be able to use JDBC. Have you checked all your permissions to make sure your app can use the internet or anything else you might need?